# Sharepoint 2010 Tasks

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have been tasked with working in SharePoint 2010. I'm very new to the game. But here's my question, I have created a task and edited it's web forms and columns. Without creating a workflow, you can create a task and it will automatically generate an e-mail to the specified person.

My question is, where in SharePoint can i edit that generic e-mail that gets sent out to the assign person without creating a workflow.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: My suggestion would be a much easier approach which is disable the default task alerts and create a workflow in designer in which you can configure the mail alert however you want

Comment: Yes i too agree with Ransher.Singh it is highly recommended not to change existing configuration. But still if you do not want to go for workflow, refer to answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Without creating workflow, you can change the task notification. But remember this will apply to all task list in web application. Email content in task notification is handled by AlertTemplates.

Alert templates are stored in the configuration database and are available at the web application level. Alert templates are defined in Alerttemplates.xml.

**Predefined alert templates**

**SPAlertTemplateType.GenericList:**

The first alert template in Alerttemplates.xml. GenericList is used unless there is a match to one of other event types.

**SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary**

Notification of changes in document libraries

**SPAlertTemplateType.Survey**

Notification of changes in surveys

**SPAlertTemplateType.Links**

Notification of changes in links

**SPAlertTemplateType.Announcements**

Notification of changes in announcements

**SPAlertTemplateType.Contacts**

Notification of changes in contacts

**SPAlertTemplateType.Events**

Notification of changes in events

**SPAlertTemplateType.Tasks**

Notification of changes in tasks

**SPAlertTemplateType.DiscussionBoard**

Notification of changes in discussion boards

**SPAlertTemplateType.PictureLibrary**

Notification of changes in picture libraries

**SPAlertTemplateType.XMLForm**

Notification of changes in XML form

**SPAlertTemplateType.DataConnectionLibrary**

Notification of changes in data connection libraries

**SPAlertTemplateType.AssignedtoNotification**

Assigned to task / issue list notifications

Alerttemplates.xml is located at: Local_Drive\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\XML directory.

**Note   Do not modify Alerttemplates.xml itself. Make changes to a working copy.**

To change the actual body of email notification, [refer this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx).

After making changes to email template, you will have to fire a stsadm Update command for changes to take effect.